# Convert Array of Javascript Objects to JSON String without the ID?

Tags: javascript, html, json, object, ecmascript-6

i'm trying to convert a large set of data into a json file, but this conversion method adds an ID in front of the objects. I've been searching for a min and can't find another way of doing this?

```
 var newDoc = [
   {
      "title": "My Title",
      "artist": "My Name"
   },
   {
      "title": "My Title 2",
      "artist": "My Name 2"
   }
 ] 

 var arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, newDoc));
 var stringToJsonObject = JSON.parse(arrayToString);
```

Result I'm getting when I console stringToJsonObject:

```
 {
    "0": {
      "title": "My Title",
      "artist": "My Name"

    },
    "1": {
      "title": "Relentless",
      "artist": "Pentagram",
    }
}
```

How do I convert it so it's just the json object without the ID.

```
{
   {
      "title": "My Title",
      "artist": "My Name"
   },
   {
      "title": "My Title 2",
      "artist": "My Name 2"
   } 
}
```

Comment: The expected result is invalid syntax.

Comment: objects need keys. which one do you want?

Comment: @Andreas Got it! How Do I remove the key? Or convert it so it doesn't have a key?

Comment: why `Object.assign`? and that's with an array?

Comment: This comment actually helped out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys are array property names for the `newDoc` array's subscripts (`0` and `1`).

They were made properties of an Object object in this expression:

```
 Object.assign({}, newDoc):
```

You could clone the input data array by omitting converting the array to an object:

```
 var arrayToString = JSON.stringify( newDoc);
 var stringToJsonObject = JSON.parse(arrayToString);
```

Note these are variable names taken from the post. Actually JSON is an acronym of "JavaScript Object Notation" and is a syntax for composing strings. To my knowledge a "json object" means an object with no recursive property references or function property values that will survive being passed as an argument to `JSON.stringify` without throwing an error.